# Display image in table

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I am trying to insert an image into table view in JavafX. Here is how I set up my table view:

```
TableColumn prodImageCol = new TableColumn("IMAGES");
    prodImageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Image>("prodImage"));
    prodImageCol.setMinWidth(100);
    // setting cell factory for product image        
    prodImageCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product,Image>,TableCell<Product,Image>>(){        
        @Override
        public TableCell<Product,Image> call(TableColumn<Product,Image> param) {                
            TableCell<Product,Image> cell = new TableCell<Product,Image>(){
                    public void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {                        
                    if(item!=null){                            
                        ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
                        imageview.setFitHeight(50);
                        imageview.setFitWidth(50);
                        imageview.setImage(new Image(product.getImage()));
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }

    });        

 viewProduct.setEditable(false);
 viewProduct.getColumns().addAll(prodImageCol, prodIDCol, prodNameCol, prodDescCol, prodPriceCol, col_action);
 viewProduct.getItems().setAll(product.populateProductTable(category));

 private SimpleObjectProperty prodImage;

 public void setprodImage(Image value) {
    prodImageProperty().set(value);
}

public Object getprodImage() {
    return prodImageProperty().get();
}

public SimpleObjectProperty prodImageProperty() {
    if (prodImage == null) {
        prodImage = new SimpleObjectProperty(this, "prodImage");
    }
    return prodImage;
}
```

And this is how I retrieve the image from database:

```
 Blob blob = rs.getBlob("productImage");
 byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
 bufferedImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
 image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImg, null);
```

However I am getting error at the setting up of table view: imageview.setImage(new Image(product.getImage()));
The error message as:

```
no suitable constructor found for Image(Image)
constructor Image.Image(String,InputStream,double,double,boolean,boolean,boolean) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Image.Image(int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Image.Image(InputStream,double,double,boolean,boolean) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Image.Image(InputStream) is not applicable
  (actual argument Image cannot be converted to InputStream by method invocation conversion)
constructor Image.Image(String,double,double,boolean,boolean,boolean) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Image.Image(String,double,double,boolean,boolean) is not applicab...
```

I did managed to retrieve and display an image inside an image view but however, I can't display it in table column. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that's causing the exception is that your method `product.getImage()` is returning an `javafx.scene.Image`.  There's no need to do anything else at this point: You have an image, so use it (before you were trying to construct `new Image(Image)` - which is not even possible).  This is what you want to be using:

```
imageview.setImage(product.getImage());
```

Your second problem is that while you're creating an `ImageView` every time you update the cell, you're not doing anything with it.  Here's your original code:

```
        TableCell<Product,Image> cell = new TableCell<Product,Image>(){
                public void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {                        
                if(item!=null){                            
                    ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
                    imageview.setFitHeight(50);
                    imageview.setFitWidth(50);
                    imageview.setImage(new Image(product.getImage()));
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
```

Like @tomsontom suggested, I'd recommend using [setGraphic(Node)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic%28javafx.scene.Node%29) to attach your `ImageView` to the `TableCell`.  So you might end up with something like this:

```
        //Set up the ImageView
        final ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
        imageview.setFitHeight(50);
        imageview.setFitWidth(50);

        //Set up the Table
        TableCell<Product,Image> cell = new TableCell<Product,Image>(){
                public void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {                        
                if(item!=null){
                    imageview.setImage(product.getImage());  //Change suggested earlier
                }
            }
        };

        // Attach the imageview to the cell
        cell.setGraphic(imageview) 
        return cell;
```

The first point @tomsontom was making is that your method of creating an Image is a little roundabout.  Sure, it seems to work... but there's a simpler way.  Originally you were using:

```
 bufferedImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
 image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImg, null);
```

But a better way of doing it would be switching those lines with:

```
 image = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

Comment: Tried that in a table, that already had text columns, to display a blob field too and `updateItem` never got called.

Comment: a) the signature of the method `updateItem` is wrong; the item type is the second type parameter (are you missing a `@Override` annotation?) b) you should set the image to `null`, if there is no `Image` to be displayed since otherwise the image is never removed, if items are removed from the table and also the references to the `Image` remains in memory, since you keep a reference in the `ImageView` (prevents garbage collection). c) probably the `ImageView` should be made a field of the `TableCell`; this grouping is more logical and allows to refracture / reuse the code more easy.

Answer (score 2):

1. why are not creating the Image directly from the data new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)) no need to rewrap it our use Swing stuff
2. I don't see a public Image(Object) constructor in FX8 - why passing it anyways if you are already have an image instance?
3. you need to set the ImageView on the cell with setGraphic()

Comment: Can you show me some example on how to solve it? Because I am still not so familiar with it

Comment: Hello? Can you please reply?