# Place an image in tableColumn - updateItem is never used

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to add an image to a tableView and went through several questions and answers and it still doesn't work.

The other fields in the tableView like name are loaded correctly.

Intelij tells me that `updateItem` is never used, which is probably why it doesn't work, but I have no idea how to debug this...

Here's what I got so far

```
    @FXML private TableColumn<PlayerManager, Image> tableColumnType;
    @FXML private void initialize(){

    tableColumnType.setCellFactory(param -> {
        //Set up the ImageView
        final ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
        imageview.setFitHeight(10);
        imageview.setFitWidth(10);
        ///imageview.setImage(imageComputer); //uncommenting this places the image on all cells, even empty ones
        //Set up the Table
        TableCell<PlayerManager, Image> cell = new TableCell<PlayerManager, Image>() {
            public void updateItem(PlayerManager item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {  // choice of image is based on values from item, but it doesn't matter now
                    imageview.setImage(imageComputer);
                }
            }
        };

        // Attach the imageview to the cell
        cell.setGraphic(imageview);
        return cell;
    });
    }
```

The questions I went through are:

[How to add an Image into a JavaFx TableView column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005115/how-to-add-an-image-into-a-javafx-tableview-column)

[Display image in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697454/display-image-in-table)

[Inserting images into TableView rows - JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601037/inserting-images-into-tableview-rows-javafx)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the cell value factory for the column, as well as the cell factory.

Comment: Did you run this in the debugger? What happened?

Comment: @James_D I didn't know it needs a `cellValueFactory` too, and what other `cellFactory` there should be?

Comment: The cell value factory determines what data the cell displays. The cell factory determines what cell is used to display the data. If you don't have a cell value factory, then the data (i.e. the `item`) passed to the cell will always be null. So if you have a `TableColumn<PlayerManager, Image>` the cell value factory should be a function that returns an `ObservableValue<Image>`. The answer to the first question you linked starts "You forgot to [use] a cellValueFactory". The other questions also use cell value factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the `updateItem` method is wrong: it should be

```
public void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) { /* ... */ }
```

If the compiler rejects the `@Override` annotation, then you know you are not defining the correct method. So you should use `@Override` and if you get a compile error, it is a signal that something is not right.

So you should be able to do

```
@FXML private TableColumn<PlayerManager, Image> tableColumnType;
@FXML private void initialize(){

tableColumnType.setCellFactory(param -> {
        //Set up the ImageView
        final ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
        imageview.setFitHeight(10);
        imageview.setFitWidth(10);
        ///imageview.setImage(imageComputer); //uncommenting this places the image on all cells, even empty ones
        //Set up the Table
        TableCell<PlayerManager, Image> cell = new TableCell<PlayerManager, Image>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {  // choice of image is based on values from item, but it doesn't matter now
                    imageview.setImage(imageComputer);
                }
            }
        };

        // Attach the imageview to the cell
        cell.setGraphic(imageview);
        return cell;
    });
}
```

If your table cell needs to access the actual `PlayerManager` object, then you need to make the table column a `TableColumn<PlayerManager, PlayerManager>` and update the `cellValueFactory` (which you haven't shown) accordingly.

Finally, note that your `updateItem(...)` method needs to deal with all cases, including empty cells for which the item is null.

So you may need something like

```
@FXML private TableColumn<PlayerManager, PlayerManager> tableColumnType;
@FXML private void initialize(){

    tableColumnType.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<PlayerManager>(cellData.getValue());

    tableColumnType.setCellFactory(param -> {
        //Set up the ImageView
        final ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
        imageview.setFitHeight(10);
        imageview.setFitWidth(10);
        ///imageview.setImage(imageComputer); //uncommenting this places the image on all cells, even empty ones
        //Set up the Table
        TableCell<PlayerManager, PlayerManager> cell = new TableCell<PlayerManager, PlayerManager>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(PlayerManager item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {  // choice of image is based on values from item, but it doesn't matter now
                    imageview.setImage(imageComputer);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImage(null);
                }
            }
        };

        // Attach the imageview to the cell
        cell.setGraphic(imageview);
        return cell;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the updateItem() method is wrong. 
Try to use:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty){
    //your code
}
```

Edit:
I think you can solve your problem by also setting a CellValueFactory for your `TableColumn`:

```
tableColumnType.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<CellDataFeatures<PlayerManager, Image>, ObservableValue<Image>(){
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Image> call(
                        CellDataFeatures<PlayerManager, Image> param) {
                    return param.getValue().exampleMethod; /* Method of your PlayerManager which returns an Image as ObservableValue. To do so you could wrap it in an `ObjectProperty<Image>`*/
                }

            }
    );
```

Comment: It now gives an error saying the method does not override from its superclass.

Comment: Could you try using Image instead of PlayerManager in the updateItem method? Does the error persist?

Comment: Now there's no error, and intelij ungrayed `updateItem`. But there's no image... Also, I'll need access to the current `PlayerManager` for choosing the right image, but now there's no access to it...

Comment: The problem is, that you told your TableColumn, that your TableView contains PlayerManager and displays images. Does your PlayerManager "gives" you the images?